# git init fails with .git/refs: No such file or directory

Tags: git

I tried making a dotfiles repository, but something went wrong so I removed it and tried to start over. Now I can't seem to `git init` anything. I even tried removing my config files:

```
cd ~
rm -r .git
rm .gitconfig
mkdir test_git
cd test_git
git init
/home/myUserName/test_git/.git: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something, or is there something wrong with my system?

```
git --version
git version 1.7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you get for

```
\ls -ld ~/.git
```

now?

I would recommend not experimenting in your home directory until the situation is understood.

How about /var/tmp or similar for your experiments?

Any errors in /var/log log files?

Does `df` show enough space on all partitions?

Comment: stackunderflow I get nothing right now, probably since I removed `.git`. I don't have administrative rights, but I'll talk to my admin...

Comment: I just wanted to know whether .git is really gone.  

Do you get `No such file or directory`?  

The `df` command should still work for you, no?  

Should give you a `Used%` well below 100% on each line.

Comment: Yes, I get `No such file or directory`. `df` shows less than 70% in use on all partitions. The issue is that `~/test_git/.git` is gone, not `~/.git`. The weird thing is that I don't think `~/test_git/.git` even should exist yet, because I just did `mkdir ~/test_git`.

Comment: Try it outside your ~ tree. I can't follow your reasoning: "The issue is that ~/test_git/.git is gone" then "I don't think ~/test_git/.git even should exist yet, because I just did mkdir ~/test_git"